# DXA 1.8 Java Application Error

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.8

I am getting the below error while I run the Java DXA 1.8 application.
Can someone help me to identify the root cause of this issue?

```
[https-jsse-nio2-4017-exec-23] ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Exception while processing request for: /
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
            at     com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.DefaultContentProvider.getStaticContentFile(DefaultContentProvider.java:95) ~[dxa-web8-provider-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
            at     com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultContentProvider.getStaticContentFile(AbstractDefaultContentProvider.java:366) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
            at     com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultContentProvider.getStaticContent(AbstractDefaultContentProvider.java:309) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
            at     com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.parseJsonFileTree(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:239) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
            at     com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.loadMainConfiguration(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:108) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
            at     com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.createLocalization(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:84) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
            at     com.sdl.webapp.tridion.AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.createLocalization(AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.java:101) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
            at     com.sdl.webapp.tridion.AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.getLocalization(AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.java:68) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
            at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.localization(WebRequestContextImpl.java:205) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
            at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.getLocalization(WebRequestContextImpl.java:85) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
            at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$2bfec188.invoke(<generated>) ~[cglib-2.2.2.jar:1.8.0]
            at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[cglib-2.2.2.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at     org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at     org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy    $DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622) ~[spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b1d5d76e.getLocalization(<generated>) ~[cglib-2.2.2.jar:1.8.0]
            at     com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.StaticContentInterceptor.preHandle(StaticContentInterceptor.java:102) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [servlet-api.jar:na]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [servlet-api.jar:na]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1697) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.processSocket(AbstractEndpoint.java:1050) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$4.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:630) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$4.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:608) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel$1.completed(SecureNio2Channel.java:917) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.29]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel$1.completed(SecureNio2Channel.java:846) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.29]
            at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126) [na:1.8.0_151]
            at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218) [na:1.8.0_151]
            at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112) [na:1.8.0_151]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.29]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

Comment: Can you verify if you are passing the right path of the url ?

Comment: The error seems to look like not able to get the localization for publication resolver,  Please edit your question provide the details how's your web app setup, did you add your domain name to topology manager website base URL?

Answer (score 5):

Let me explain how to interpret such a Stack Trace:

- The exception is a `NullPointerException`, meaning that the code tried to dereference a pointer which is `null`. This generally means the code is not robust enough: it did not expect that a pointer could get a `null` value, but it did.
- The first line in the Stack Trace reveals where this exception occurred: in method `DefaultContentProvider.getStaticContentFile`, defined in source file `DefaultContentProvider.java` at line 95.

  - The class is deployed as part of JAR `dxa-web8-provider-1.8.0.jar` (which reveals both the version of DXA and the name of the project)
- Subsequent lines give information about the context of where the exception occurred.

  - Interesting lines are `LocalizationFactoryImpl.loadMainConfiguration` and `LocalizationFactoryImpl.createLocalization`.
  - So, apparently, the exception occured when trying to load a "main configuration" as part of creating a "Localization". Indeed, DXA loads configuration data (stored in the CD Content Store and cached on file system) when a new Localization is initialized.
  - If we got this far, apparently the Localization has already been resolved. So, there does not seem to be an issue with Topology Manager and/or Discovery Service. The problem lies in loading the configuration data.
- Now let's go back to that first line and find the source code to get a better idea of what happened.

  - Since we're talking about a problem in the DXA Java Web Application (Framework), the source code can be found here: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java
  - Since the DXA version is 1.8.0, we should be using the [`release/1.8`](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/tree/release/1.8/dxa-framework) branch.
  - Since the artifact was `dxa-web8-provider-1.8.0.jar`, we should look into [`dxa-web8-provider`](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/tree/release/1.8/dxa-framework/dxa-web8-provider)
  - The fully qualified name of the class is `com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.DefaultContentProvider`. This helps us to navigate to the class in GitHub: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/release/1.8/dxa-framework/dxa-web8-provider/src/main/java/com/sdl/webapp/tridion/mapping/DefaultContentProvider.java
  - Now, let's see what's at line 95: `writeToFile(file, pathInfo, binaryData.getBytes());`
  - OK, so it's trying to write binary data to a file. There is only one thing on this line that can cause a `NullPointerException`: `binaryData.getBytes()`.  That is: if `binaryData` is `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException`.
  - So, how did `binaryData` get `null`?  We have to look at preceding lines to see how `binaryData` got set. At line 92 we find: `BinaryData binaryData = binaryContentRetriever.getBinary(publicationId, itemId, binaryMeta.getVariantId());`
- Altogether, we now have a pretty good picture:

  - As part of Localization intialization, some configuration data is loaded in the form of a Binary in the CD Content Store, which then gets written/cached to file system.
  - However, it seems the Binary cannot be retrieved from CD Content Store and the CD API returns a `null` pointer.
  - The DXA code does not expect this `null` pointer and this results in a `NullPointerException`.

Question remains: why can that Binary not be found in the CD Content Store? Typical reasons for this are:

- The CM Publication is not published to CD yet.  In particular: this kind of Configuration data (stored as Binaries in CD) is published by the "Publish Settings" Page.

  - Actually, if the Binary was not published at all, we wouldn't have gotten this far in the code, because then there would not even have been metadata about the binary (see line 92 and earlier in the source code: before trying to retrieve the Binary data, some metadata about the binary is retrieved first).
- The CD Deployer is configured to store Binaries on file system instead of in the CD Content Store (database).

  - This seems to be the most plausible explanation of how such an exception can occur.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Now I am getting, "Publication mapping not found. Check if your cd_dynamic_conf.xml configuration file contains a publication mapping that matches this URL"<MYAPPLICATION URL>

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. Please create a separate Question and provide sufficient context info (e.g. what’s in Topology Manage? How do your URLs look?)