# DXA 1.8 "BinaryData" files is not creating under \dxaWeb\BinaryData\publication-id\system\config\ when I build dxaWeb app

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, java, dxa-1.8

I have upgraded DXA 1.5 to DXA 1.8, Java 1.7 to 1.8. Deploying in Tomcat 9 server. The `BinaryData` files is not creating under `\dxaWeb\BinaryData\publication-id\system\config\` when I build DXA web app. I'm getting a null pointer exception. I have published all Pages (under my site SG)

If you see the error log: this content service request returing the data - DEBUG BasicEndpointCaller - Preparing the call endpoint for given url: http://domain:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetComponentMetaFunctionImport(ComponentId=216112,PublicationId=826)

but this call is not returning any data. so,I'm getting null exception. I'm not sure why it's not returning the data. when I check the data in DB. I can see the binaryId related data in broker DB

DEBUG BasicEndpointCaller - Preparing the call endpoint for given url: http://domain:8081/client/v2/content.svc/BinaryContents%28PublicationId%3D826%2CBinaryId%3D216112%2CVariantId%3DY29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA%3D%3D%2CStreamContent%3Dfalse%29

Can you please help me to fix the below issue?

```
2018-12-17 11:03:29,982 DEBUG LocalizationFactoryImpl - createLocalization: [826] /
2018-12-17 11:03:29,985 DEBUG DynamicMetaRetrieverImpl - Searching for binaryMeta for url='http://localhost:9080/system/config/_all.json'.
2018-12-17 11:03:30,009 DEBUG DefaultODataClient - Getting entity for query ODataClientQuery[GetDynamicMetaFunctionImport(Url='http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9080%252Fsystem%252Fconfig%252F_all.json',ItemType='BinaryMeta')]
2018-12-17 11:03:30,009 DEBUG BasicEndpointCaller - Preparing the call endpoint for given url: http://domain:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetDynamicMetaFunctionImport(Url='http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9080%252Fsystem%252Fconfig%252F_all.json',ItemType='BinaryMeta')
2018-12-17 11:03:30,112 DEBUG BasicEndpointCaller - Request ended with 200 status code.
2018-12-17 11:03:30,113 DEBUG AtomEntityUnmarshaller - Unmarshalling entity for query: ODataClientQuery[GetDynamicMetaFunctionImport(Url='http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9080%252Fsystem%252Fconfig%252F_all.json',ItemType='BinaryMeta')]
2018-12-17 11:03:30,114 DEBUG DynamicMetaRetrieverImpl - Retrieved BinaryMeta instance: [BinaryMeta tcd:pub[826]/variant[config-bootstrap]/binarymeta[216112], application/json, /system/config/_all.json, /system/config/_all.json]
2018-12-17 11:03:30,140 DEBUG DefaultODataClient - Getting entity for query ODataClientQuery[GetComponentMetaFunctionImport(ComponentId=216112,PublicationId=826)]
2018-12-17 11:03:30,141 DEBUG BasicEndpointCaller - Preparing the call endpoint for given url: http://domain:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetComponentMetaFunctionImport(ComponentId=216112,PublicationId=826)
2018-12-17 11:03:30,176 DEBUG BasicEndpointCaller - Request ended with 200 status code.
2018-12-17 11:03:30,176 DEBUG AtomEntityUnmarshaller - Unmarshalling entity for query: ODataClientQuery[GetComponentMetaFunctionImport(ComponentId=216112,PublicationId=826)]
2018-12-17 11:03:30,179 DEBUG WebComponentMetaFactoryImpl - Retrieved ComponentMeta instance: com.sdl.web.model.ComponentMetaImpl@25ae51ff
2018-12-17 11:03:30,180 DEBUG BinaryContentRetrieverImpl - Searching for binaryData for publicationId='826', binaryId='216112', variantId='config-bootstrap'.
2018-12-17 11:03:30,188 DEBUG DefaultODataClient - Getting entity for query ODataClientQuery[BinaryContents%28PublicationId%3D826%2CBinaryId%3D216112%2CVariantId%3DY29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA%3D%3D%2CStreamContent%3Dfalse%29]
2018-12-17 11:03:30,189 DEBUG BasicEndpointCaller - Preparing the call endpoint for given url: http://domain:8081/client/v2/content.svc/BinaryContents%28PublicationId%3D826%2CBinaryId%3D216112%2CVariantId%3DY29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA%3D%3D%2CStreamContent%3Dfalse%29
2018-12-17 11:03:30,228 DEBUG BasicEndpointCaller - Request ended with 200 status code.
2018-12-17 11:03:30,228 DEBUG AtomEntityUnmarshaller - Unmarshalling entity for query: ODataClientQuery[BinaryContents%28PublicationId%3D826%2CBinaryId%3D216112%2CVariantId%3DY29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA%3D%3D%2CStreamContent%3Dfalse%29]
2018-12-17 11:03:30,229 DEBUG DefaultContentProvider - Writing binary content to file: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\wtpwebapps\dxaWeb\BinaryData\826\system\config\_all.json
Dec 17, 2018 11:03:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.DefaultContentProvider.getStaticContentFile(DefaultContentProvider.java:95)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultContentProvider.getStaticContentFile(AbstractDefaultContentProvider.java:366)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultContentProvider.getStaticContent(AbstractDefaultContentProvider.java:309)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.parseJsonFileTree(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:239)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.loadMainConfiguration(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.createLocalization(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.createLocalization(AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.java:101)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.getLocalization(AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.java:68)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.localization(WebRequestContextImpl.java:205)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.getLocalization(WebRequestContextImpl.java:85)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$2bfec188.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7633fbaa.getLocalization(<generated>)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.StaticContentInterceptor.preHandle(StaticContentInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:914)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you have a look at Rick's response below? He has stated all the steps in detail.
https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18997/dxa-1-8-java-application-error. If you can update the question with your findings, it may be quicker to figure the issue. Does the DXA 1.7 code work without any issues with the topology that you have configured? Is the DXA 1.7 and 1.8 code deployed to the same server?

Comment: I saw Rick's response. I have published all pages but still same error. We're upgrading DXA 1.5 to 1.8. DXA 1.5 we were not using micro service but 1.8 we are using micro service. 1.8 am trying in my local machine but still it's not working.  this content service is not returning the data. that's why it's throwing null.  BasicEndpointCaller - Preparing the call endpoint for given url: http://domain:8081/client/v2/content.svc/BinaryContents%28PublicationId%3D826%2CBinaryId%3D216112%2CVariantId%3DY29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA%3D%3D%2CStreamContent%3Dfalse%29

Comment: Good. It becomes more of an access issue with the CD services then. I would first disable OAUTH in your CD services and try to get a response from a browser. Suggest that you ask a new question or change your existing question to get better information!

Comment: thanks for the response. if it's access issue. it should not give any response from content service right but this request giving data http://domain:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetComponentMetaFunctionImport(ComponentId=216112,PublicationId=826) but this is not http://domain:8081/client/v2/content.svc/BinaryContents%28PublicationId%3D826%2CBinaryId%3D216112%2CVariantId%3DY29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA%3D%3D%2CStreamContent%3Dfalse%29

Comment: Do you have your "ContentServiceCapability" registered with your discovery service? You would not have to use v2 and v4, the CD API should be able to take care of it. Can you answer your own question and open a new question with the issue the you are facing? At this point, your question is outdated.

Comment: I'm not giving the v2 or v4. DXA framework is building the call. yes we have "ContentServiceCapability" role setup in under content service config file cd_storage_conf.xml. Still I do not understand why the 2nd call is not returning the data since it's not returning the data so it's throws null exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below content service query was not returning any data. So, that none of the files were not generating since it's was throwing null exception

BasicEndpointCaller - Preparing the call endpoint for given url: `http://domain:8081/client/v2/content.svc/BinaryContents%28PublicationId%3D826%2CBinaryId%3D216112%2CVariantId%3DY29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA%3D%3D%2CStreamContent%3Dfalse%29`